# Android data (text+image) storage

Tags: android, image

I want to create an android application containing the following data:

Text in four different languages, a date and an image.

My problem is that I don't know the best way to store those data. They should be available for the lambda user but not easily visible (--> not on the sd card for example). Without image, I would directly have chosen sqlite but... with it, whats the best?

assets? sqlite(+ image as blob)? sqlite(+ path to image)? XML? JSON?

Also, I want to randomly pick one of my about 1000 entries and thos entries will probably be inserted by someone who has low computer science knowledges.

Comment: you can also store image in sqlite....

Comment: Any reason not to use the resource system (works for localized images too)? http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html

Comment: Of course localization is nice with resource system, but are hard to maintain with a link to a date and an image.

Answer (score 1):

The files that are stored inside your application folder are private to your application and cannot be easily accessed.

So easiest would be to have the text as xml and images as assets inside your app folder.

Comment: XML structure like that(sorry for the formatting): <entries> <entry> <title> <eng></eng> <fr></fr> <it></it> </title> <text> <eng></eng> <fr></fr> <it></it> </text> <pathToImage></pathToImage> <date></date> </entry> </entries>  ???

Answer (score 0):

If the images are static (ie.. not downloaded but distributed with your app) I would put these in assets (drawable).

With regards to the text, you could use strings.xml and localize this for the other 3 languages.

Hope I have understood your problem here.

Comment: The problem is that it is hard to maintain with 1000 objects. 1000 entries in strings.xml are already chaotic but id thos entries also have a link to a Drawable, it will be a mess? don't you think?

Comment: OK .. from your question it appeared you had 4 text an image and a date. It will be hard to manage but strings.xml is the recommended way to localize text AFAIK.

Comment: Something I didn't say before is that I want to randomly pick one of my 1000 entries. You would recommand me to put thos objects in an array of strings with an id? and how could I link them to the image? Also It could be interesting to havec a title for each entry. 

I could create an XML file like this in the assets:
<entries>
 <entry>
  <title>
   <eng></eng>
   <fr></fr>
   <it></it>
  </title>
  <text>
   <eng></eng>
   <fr></fr>
   <it></it>
  </text>
  <pathToImage></pathToImage>
  <date></date>
 </entry>
</entries>

Comment: or the same structure in a db? Storing images as blob in a DB is in my opinion nicer but much harder to insert.

or directories in assets like that?
yyyymmdd/image.jpg
        /text_eng.txt
        /text_fr.txt
        /text_it.txt
        /title_eng.txt
        /title_fr.txt
        /title_it.txt

It's harder to access but much easier to maintain.

Another point is that I won't create the entries and that somebody with low computer science knowledge will. The directory version would be easier...

Comment: With that volume then sqlite would be the way to go, like you have said 1 row for 1 entry (image, 4 text fields, date). How are you imagining that the DB will be populated? By an entry screen on the device? or by someone before release?

Comment: Someone before release. Is there an easy way to populate the DB? and to convert images to BLOB if I don't use path to images?

Comment: I don't know about BLOB, but there are sqlite managers (for example @ http://sourceforge.net/projects/sqlitebrowser/) that will allow you to manually enter the info. It also has an export to SQL Query option which could be included then into the code, or just use the created sqlite db